# Execute a terminal command that takes an argument from terminal in python a 2.6 script

Tags: python, linux, bash, command-line-arguments

My environment uses Python 2.6 and I'm new to Python. I need to write a script that runs a file decoding command which takes several arguments from the command line. My problem is I can't parse arguments taken from the terminal to the file decoding command.

For example if my program name is x.py and when i run "x.py Desktop/abc.txt" how can i pass Desktop/abc.txt as an argument to the cat command?

```
import commands
import sys

a=open("b.txt","w") 
a.write(commands.getoutput('cat sys.argv[1]'))
```

When i researched it seemed that the above program should work but it didn't. Please help.

Comment: take a look at [calling-an-external-command-in-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Comment: I did but it didn't help in this case. Contents of abc.txt must be there in the b.txt file but all it contains is "cat: sys.argv[1]: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `commands.getoutput('cat sys.argv[1]')` as `commands.getoutput('cat %s' % (sys.argv[1],))`

Comment: or even better `subprocess.check_output(["cat",sys.argv[1]]).read()`

Comment: @ellipse42 thanks a lot it solved my problem :) Say cat takes 4 arguments

Comment: Say cat takes 4 arguments where 2 of them are integers, 1 is a string and 1 is a variable named log which has read contents of a file to it. So is it ('cat %s%s%d%d' % (sys.argv[1], log,sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2]))

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up the terminal commands and Python commands. If you have a file called `abc.py` with the following code:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

And you run it with `python abc.py arg1`, it should print out `arg1`.

For a cleaner and easier to read way of using command-line arguments if you want to control things like make sure they are `int` or allow multiple or whatever, I've had a lot of success using the `argparse` module in Python - it's much easier to use than the `sys.argv` style of parsing command-line arguments. Check out the official tutorial / docs here: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: The `getopt` module can be useful for defining acceptable options and arguments that can be passed to the program and filtering out unacceptable ones.